# How to create a scheduler in spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

What I need to implement is a scheduler that will be making rest calls periodically. We are using spring webflux. I know the **@Scheduled**, **@EnableScheduling** annotations of spring
but here in this case(spring-webflux) what is the possible option?

Here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux also unable to find anything related to what I want to do (i.e. making periodic rest calls).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `@Scheduled`is a fully viable option it is part of the `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation` package which means it has nothing to do with spring web etc. If you application is the consumer (for example you are making a periodic rest call and then lets say updating a database from your application) then you are the consumer and using `subscribe` is a fully valid usage here to execute the request.

Comment: Yes, I have used that, all worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: Hi,I have faced a same question and i try to do just enabled @EnableScheduling and with @Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * *"). This is not working. How you made this possible?

Comment: @D.Anush what is the exact problem you are facing?